# Can I use $_POST & $_GET at the same time?

Tags: php

I have a following form:

```
<form action="doThis.php?warehouse=12" method="post">
  <input name="field1" type="text" />
  <input name="field2" type="text" />
</form>
```

And `doThis.php`:

```
$field1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['field1'], $mysql);
$field2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['field2'], $mysql);

$warehouse = $_GET['warehouse'];
if ( !someTableNameValidation($warehouse) ) {
    someErrorHandling();
}
$qry = "INSERT INTO table".$warehouse." ( field1, field2 ) VALUES( '$field2', '$field2') ";
$result = @mysql_query($qry, $mysql);
```

As you can see, I'm using $_POST to get data from the form, and $_GET to get variable `$warehouse` which is used to indicate table number.

**Can I use both $_POST & $_GET at the same time? Is this kind of usage correct?**

Comment: This looks okay but do not use this kind of practice while including the pages like `required($variable)` or in require_once or include. Some user can pass their own path which will harm your server or document.

Comment: Incidentally this is why `$_REQUEST` exists. It combines `$_GET` and `$_POST` into one array. (For older setups can also contain `$_COOKIES` which could lead to value fixation issues. But generally still useful.)

Comment: @mario -can you provide an example of converting my example into `$_REQUEST` usage. Is this any simpler?

Comment: Just replace any occurence of $_GET and $_POST with $_REQUEST. In your example only the `warehouse` parameter needs adaption though; and as said this is only sensible if you surely never want to use a `warehouse` cookie later on. (Else you have to guard the php.ini setting request_order.)

Comment: You have to set the `method="post"` attribute on the form element, `get` is the default.

Comment: @mario - I could actually use `$_SESSION or  $_COOKIE` for storing this data, as it will be used all the time till new `$warehouse` value will be set (`unset $_SESSION / $_COOKIE & set new one` ), but `$_POST & $_GET` is just simpler for the moment.

Comment: Then it's best to use the explicit arrays. $_REQUEST is only meant for input that can occur likewise in GET or POST data.

Comment: @VolkerK - good point, I have missed that in my example.

Comment: @NewUser fixed that and added some code to avoid unnecessary (i.e beside the point of this particular question) security related discussions. But if it's not only an example but something you really want to do, keep in mind that there are several issuse with this approach and you might want to ask another question on how to implement the thing you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I always do that.

Also note you should never use mysql_query. Search for php `PDO`. Not to mention the awful `@` for suppressing error

Comment: "`you should never use mysql_query`" - Um what? It totaly depends on what you are doing.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg  - as this will be the code behind secure login + verification on the top of every page, this code should be sql injection protect, should it not?

Comment: @NewUser, Of course, but as I said: It depends on what you are doing. If you are just selecting some data with no input parameters from external sources, why would you not be able to use `mysq_query`? Saying that you should NEVER use it is a bold statement.

Comment: @NewUser: Just using PDO does not make SQL queries secure. You also have to use parameterized/bound parameters, otherwise it's pointless. And in your example you cannot do that, as the `table$NN` name is variable. So you need manual sanitizing and filtering. So you might as well keep using the outdated mysql_query thing. (PDO and bound parameters are more imporantantly for convenience, security is a by-product.)

Comment: @Filip Ekberg - what do you mean by `bold statement`?

Comment: @mario - so when you are using PDO with parameterized/bound parameters you cannot use `$variables` anywhere in the SQL statement?

Comment: @NewUser: You *can* combine the two approaches. But it kind of defeats the purpose. You're still allowed to build dynamic SQL queries, but injecting variables is generally frowned on, as that makes it just as likley to overlook some sanitizing.

Comment: @mario - as the `$varibale` will be send the same way as the inputed data. Does it not allow to use same security on it?

Comment: @NewUser: If we are talking about PDO here, no. You see only `data` can be used as bound parameters. Table names and identifiers cannot. You cannot pass something like `INSERT INTO ? (...)` and then the bound parameter `table$NNN` into PDO. That's not supported, why you would have to string-inject it as dynamic SQL. So you *do* very much need to handle the filtering itself. Just needs an `intval()` typecast in your case; but you have to always reexamine that it's done on each occurence in your whole application...

Comment: also PDO makes your queries more portable.using mysql_* functions you are stuck with mysql.if you want to change db engine some day you will have to rewrite all your mysql statements.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could. `$_GET['warehouse']` will be taken from the query string, `$_POST` variables from submitted POST values.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. But you could also use a hidden field:

```
<form action="doThis.php">
<input type="hidden" name="warehouse" value="12" />
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
```

Please be aware that your code is **very vulnerable to sql injections**!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however it should be:

```
$field1 = $_POST['field1'];
$field2 = $_POST['field2'];

$warehouse = $_GET['warehouse'];

$qry = "INSERT INTO table".$warehouse." ( field1, field2 ) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($field2)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($field2)."')";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

(Fixed syntax)

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use POST and GET together, so that the PHP side can know whether it was a normal form submission or via AJAX.

```
<form action='dest.php'>
.
.
.
```

vs

```
ajaxSubmit( 'dest.php?a=1', ... );
```

Comment: You can check if a request was submitted via AJAX using: `strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])`. If it is AJAX it will equal `xmlhttprequest`.