# How to pick up form details using POST request from a PHP page which was accessed using GET request

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I have executed a php script through GET request
ex:

```
http://localhost/example.php?id=9&name=exammple
```

Now the example.php has a form field

```
<form method="post" action="example.php">

---form fields used to post data on server---

</form>
```

Now on submitting the form, it throws up an error saying undefined indexes.

How do I submit a form in a page which was accessed using GET request? I am a PHP beginner.

Comment: Post the code of your script and the form too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203715/can-i-use-post-get-at-the-same-time/7203746#7203746

Comment: @AlecSmart: `$_REQUEST` contains `$_COOKIES`, too. That's not what it is asked for. I just draw the line, because this can lead to grey areas in input processing. Just a little reminder.

Comment: @Alec DO NOT use $_REQUEST. It won't solve the OP's problem anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<form method="post" action="">`
Then it will post the data to the same page (with the GET parameters) and you can get them using $_GET and the parameters from the form using $_POST or all with $_REQUEST.

Comment: Your idea worked ... I want to know just in case is this idea vulnerable to sql injections or any other security attack?

Comment: There is always a security risk with receiving user input. So always check if the data is what you would expect and escape the data. However that has nothing to do with combining POST and GET like this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a

```
$_POST += $_GET;
```

before you access the `$_POST` variables or use anther request variable like [`$_REQUEST`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) if you want to allow others next to `$_GET`, too (namely `$_COOKIES` with PHP's default configuration).

A little explanation:

- `$_GET` - contains all get variables.
- `$_POST` - contains all post variables.

The

```
$_POST += $_GET;
```

will put all *get variables* into `$_POST` if they have not been send as *post variable* by [creating a union](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) of `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: What's the point in all that mess? Why such a stupid idea of putting get variables into post array? any reason?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: You should read more carefully both question and answer. I think you know enough about PHP that you understand it. It's pretty dumb to just throw non-saying adjectives onto something when you place your perception out of context, but if you have anything constructive to share, please do so. I have the feeling you have some thoughts to share, but I was not able to decipher their meaning from your comment.