# how top use GET and POST simultaneusly

Tags: php

I have a page in php that gets from the url such as this code example

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="get">
//some interesting code here
</form>
```

The issue now is that when i do the GET depending on its value I need to do a POST,

How can I use `action="get"` and `action="post"` in the same page?, I am kind of new to PHP so I am not sure if I can use two  tags ("i dont think so but please correct me if i am wrong").

PS: I am getting to the same page "welcome.php" and posting to itself again, and depending on the value I am going to show different content.

Thank you

Comment: It's common for scripts to accept GET and POST parameters simultaneously, but why do you need to use a single form to submit both GET and POST parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use $_POST & $_GET at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203715/can-i-use-post-get-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Related: [How to pick up form details using POST request from a PHP page which was accessed using GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7736846/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but if I'm understanding it correctly, you can certainly pass GET variables via the `form`'s `action`:

```
<form action="welcome.php?these=are&amp;get=variables" method="post">
//some interesting code here
</form>
```

Comment: That's not a fun fact, that's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You may access both through `$_REQUEST` if necessary. So no matter what your `method` type is, `$_REQUEST` will contain all of your submitted values. This way you don't need to determine whether it was by post, or by get that the data was submitted.

Comment: Using `$_REQUEST` is bad practice though. http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Comment: @Galen I agree, it's not always a good option and it should be used with caution.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to trap the $_GET value as a hidden var, so when the post is submitted again, your $_GET value will be available:

```
if (array_key_exists('myVar', $_GET)) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="myVar" value="' . $_GET['myVar'] .'" />
}

// Now when you resubmit the form you should have access to 'myVar'

echo $_REQUEST['myVar'];
```

You could also add the get value to the session super global:

```
if (array_key_exists('myVar', $_GET)) {
    $_SESSION['myVar'] = $_GET['myVar'];
}

// Now when you resubmit the form you should have access to 'myVar'

echo $_SESSION['myVar'];
```